# Error in my build.gradle file when trying to implement the Google Calendar API

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have been trying to implement the google calendar api to my Spring maven project. I have followed the steps from the Google developer website https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java but have been getting an error when I have to run the command "gradle -q run".

The error is shown below:

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\workspace\Project\build.gradle' line: 17

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Project'.

> Supplied String module notation 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

The build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Quickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev285-1.23.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority'
    compile 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired'
    compile 'org.springframework.stereotype.Service'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager'
    compile 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired'
    compile 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'
    compile 'org.slf4j.Logger'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'
    compile 'org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param'
    compile 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query'
    compile 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository'
    compile 'javax.persistence.*'
    compile 'javax.persistence.Table'
    compile 'javax.persistence.ManyToOne'
    compile 'javax.persistence.JoinColumn'
    compile 'javax.persistence.Id'
    compile 'javax.persistence.GenerationType'
    compile 'javax.persistence.GeneratedValue'
    compile 'javax.persistence.Entity'
    compile 'javax.persistence.OneToOne'
    compile 'javax.persistence.NamedQuery'
    compile 'javax.persistence.NamedQueries'
    compile 'javax.persistence.FetchType'
    compile 'javax.persistence.CascadeType'

}
```

Comment: These are `import` statements not libraries. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was missing dependencies in the build.gradle file. I was getting an error like this: "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\eeworkspace\Project\src\main\java\‌​com\fyp\account\serv‌​ice\UserDetailsServi‌​ceImpl.java:13: error: package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; ". I am trying to implement the google calendar api to my project @Opal